# Trying to look at existing list in Excel, if we find a specified phrase, append specified data into further columns

Tags: python, excel

I hope this all makes sense as I explain it, please do ask for further clarification if needed! Apologies if my Python vocab isn't up to scratch - I'm still quite a beginner but have been set this task by work.

I'm trying to write a script that will save me, and other colleagues, time on a task - we have to take a list of items from within buildings, and they need to all be categorised using a system called 'Uniformat'. Each building has it's own excel so this is a repetitive task that takes approx. 7 working days to complete.

I have the list of items within the building (thousands of rows), so the script needs to look at the list, and if it finds a specific phrase, for example 'Door_Type01_FR60_ARN/A' then it will fill in the 4 columns along that row with the correct Uniformat Data - this will be built into the script so it knows what to input for each object/phrase)
The resulting Excel (or csv, doesn't matter) would then look like -

Column A:
Door_Type01_FR60_ARN/A
Column B:
A
Column C:
A10
Column D:
A1020
Column E:
A102030

Ideally, I then take the script, and get it to look at the next building list and so on, adding any extra info for each specific building.

At the moment, I have a script that I have to tell to look at the First Unique Value, and populate that data on everything with that value, then the Second Unique Value, Third Unique Value and so on:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\etc etc etc.csv',encoding='latin-1')
data2 = data["Description (Type - Name)"]
Unique_Values = pd.unique(data2)
print(Unique_Values)
  
First_Unique_Value = Unique_Values[0]
List1 = [str(First_Unique_Value),'D','D50 Electrical','D5030 COMMUNICATIONS & SECURITY','D503090 OTHER COMMUNICATIONS & ALARM SYSTEMS']
List1 = pd.DataFrame(List1)
List1 = List1[0].values.reshape(1,5)
List1 = pd.DataFrame(List1)

Second_Unique_Value = Unique_Values[1]
List2 = [str(Second_Unique_Value),'C','C30 INTERIOR FINISHES','C3030 CEILING FINISHES','C303002 GYPSUM WALLBOARD CEILING FINISHES']
List2 = pd.DataFrame(List2)
List2 = List2[0].values.reshape(1,5)
List2 = pd.DataFrame(List2)
```

The problem is that every building has a list of objects that are not ordered/are completely different from each other, so the above is taking as long as manually applying the Uniformat data because I have to go through and tell it what data goes with each unique value in the list, which can be thousands of rows in Excel.

Any ideas of how I can build this in a way that will just scan for certain phrases and populate the data?

Thanks!

EDIT: Screenshot of .csv input AND the output I need:

[CSV INPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTgEQ.png)

[EXPECTED OUTPUT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yELyx.png)

Comment: Side note: a CSV file is not an Excel file (i.e the Excel tag is not applicable here).

Comment: Thanks @BigBen! I put it as Excel as the output can be Excel or csv, and it was those 2 that were suggested haha :) never posted a question before so wasn't sure

Comment: Could you please provide a small sample of your input CSV files?

Comment: @PubuduSitinamaluwa added screenshot of a section of the .csv as well as the expected output. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are having trouble processing a lot of different CSVs. Hope this would be a better approach to solve it.

Here is the sample csv I used.

*EDIT* : Column name updated to A to take the hole as a single column as requested.

```
A
Door_Type01,010x2,100_FR60_ARN/A
Door_Type03,010x2,100_FR60_ARN/A
Door_Type01,010x2,100_FR60_ARN/A
Door_Type01,010x2
Door_Type02,010x2,100_FR60_ARN/A
Door_Type04,010x2,100_FR60_ARN/A
Door_Type01,010x2,100_FR60_ARN/A
Door_Type04,010x2,100_FR60_ARN/A
Door_Ceil_Type02,010x2,100_FR60_ARN/A
Door_Type01,
```

I came up with a mapping for different types of search strings and replacements with a number of columns named `col1`, `col2`, `col3`, and `col4`.
You can updae the mapping to add new types and replacements to work on different csvs.

*EDIT* : Changed search_types to a regex like syntax by adding `.*` at the end.

```py
type_map = {
    'Door_Type01.*': {
        'col1': 'D', 'col2': 'D50 Electrical', 'col3': 'D5030 COMMUNICATIONS & SECURITY', 'col4': 'D503090 OTHER COMMUNICATIONS & ALARM SYSTEMS'
    },
    'Door_Type02.*': {
        'col1': 'HERE', 'col2': 'GOES', 'col3': 'OTHER', 'col4': 'VALUES'
    }
}
```

And to add the columns

*EDIT* : Changed the match condition in `np.where()` clause from `data["A"] == search_type` to `data.A.str.match(pattern)` with introduced new regex pattern.

```py
# Columns marked as A in the csv. Delimiter changed to `\t` and null values replaced with '' for clarity
data = pd.read_csv('./sample.csv', encoding='latin-1', header=0, delimiter="\t").fillna('')

for search_type, columnsValues in type_map.items():
    pattern = re.compile(search_type)
    for colName, cellValue in columnsValues.items():
        data[colName] = np.where(data.A.str.match(pattern), cellValue, data[colName] if colName in data.columns else '')
```

Output

```py
print(data.to_string())
```

```
                                       A  col1            col2                             col3                                          col4
0       Door_Type01,010x2,100_FR60_ARN/A     D  D50 Electrical  D5030 COMMUNICATIONS & SECURITY  D503090 OTHER COMMUNICATIONS & ALARM SYSTEMS
1       Door_Type03,010x2,100_FR60_ARN/A                                                                                                     
2       Door_Type01,010x2,100_FR60_ARN/A     D  D50 Electrical  D5030 COMMUNICATIONS & SECURITY  D503090 OTHER COMMUNICATIONS & ALARM SYSTEMS
3                      Door_Type01,010x2     D  D50 Electrical  D5030 COMMUNICATIONS & SECURITY  D503090 OTHER COMMUNICATIONS & ALARM SYSTEMS
4       Door_Type02,010x2,100_FR60_ARN/A  HERE            GOES                            OTHER                                        VALUES
5       Door_Type04,010x2,100_FR60_ARN/A                                                                                                     
6       Door_Type01,010x2,100_FR60_ARN/A     D  D50 Electrical  D5030 COMMUNICATIONS & SECURITY  D503090 OTHER COMMUNICATIONS & ALARM SYSTEMS
7       Door_Type04,010x2,100_FR60_ARN/A                                                                                                     
8  Door_Ceil_Type02,010x2,100_FR60_ARN/A                                                                                                     
9                            Door_Type01     D  D50 Electrical  D5030 COMMUNICATIONS & SECURITY  D503090 OTHER COMMUNICATIONS & ALARM SYSTEMS
```

Comment: Thanks @Pubudu. This is definitely more towards where I aim to be! The data from the csv comes through in just one column, with the value being something like 'HLM_Door_Type01-1,010x2,100_FR60_ARN/A' and the bit I'm looking at is 'HLM_Door_Type01-1,010x2,100_FR60' 
Using this code, if that one column is column 'A', would the second section of code need changing? I'm getting this to run but it isn't mapping the values to the additional columns and I'm not sure which bit needs to change.

Comment: I think replacing data["A"] == search_type expression to a regular expression match could do the trick.

Comment: @franny_sanny I have updated the answer. Please check carefully for updates and see if this works for you.